# Move VSTS subscription to new work account

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I'm struggling with moving our VSTS subscription (and all projects within it) to a new MS work Azure account.

The original VSTS subscription was created on a personal account (call it a@a.com) and I want to move it to a@a.onmicrosoft.com.

When I am in the azure portal I can see the Team Service as a resource. I've unlinked it from any active directory.

Now, while it has a subscription key, I cannot seem to access the subscription. There is no link and there are zero subscriptions listed on the subscriptions list in Azure portal. it seems to be orphaned or something.

I have tried adding a@a.onmicrosoft.com as a user to the VSTS account within VSTS but it seems to add it as a personal account, so I cannot log in to it using my work account.

I have managed to change the owner in VSTS to a Gmail account, but it's still showing as a resource in my a@a.com personal Azure account.

I have tried to find up to date information on this but several pages mention adding a co administrator, but either this is no longer possible or I cannot do it because there appears to be no subscription association with the VSTS resource.

I'm desperate, please help!

Comment: Do you refer to this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/change-azure-active-directory-vsts-account

Answer (score 2):

In the end I had to raise a support ticket with VSTS support who performed some kind of migration that I would have been unable to do myself.